# The meaning of the particles in "Yume no naka futari de ita yo ne"

Tags: translation, particle-で, particle-ね, particle-よ

The phrase

> Yume no naka futari de ita yo ne

is translated in a page as

> In my dreams, we were together

I don't understand the meaning of the particles here, plus where the 'together' comes from. *Yume no naka* is 'inside of my dreams' I suppose, *futari* would be 'the two of us' and *ita* the past of *iru* which would be 'were' but where is the 'together'? What does the *yo ne* adds here? And *de* is supposed to be a particle that indicates the place where an action happens, but here is after 'the two of us'?

Comment: It looks like you meant to put in a translation, but you accidentally repeated the romanized Japanese text instead.

Comment: @snailplane I didnt understand your comment until now, I'm so distracted

Comment: You ask about 'together' but I don't see that word in the translation.  Can you clarify what 'together' you're asking about?

Comment: @snailplane sorry again, now ^_^;;;;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particle "de" 「で」 doesn't just mark the location where something happens. It's also used to mark the *means* by which something happens. Which can include more direct things like "the tool by which an action was performed" (e.g. I went to Tokyo *by bullet train* - *densha de* Tokyo ni itta) but can also mark more abstract ideas. So "futari de" 「二人で」 means "by way of the two of us", or in other words "[do it] together". Since the verb here is just "ita", it's "we were together".

Comment: Interesting in English it's "by myself" but "as a couple".

Comment: what about yo ne? what connotation does it give to the phrase?

Comment: As Takahiro Waki says in another answer, "yo ne" adds a bit of emphasis and a bit of uncertainty. Typically if you just have "yo" at the end of a sentence, it's almost like adding an exclamation mark, while "ne" is like you're asking for confirmation - "sou desu ne" = "that's true, isn't it?". So "yo ne" is like "I'm sure we were in the dream together, weren't we?"

Answer (score 1):

I see translation failed. "yume no naka futari de ita yone" is "Both you and me were in same dream, weren't we". This is included part of yone.